# How to segment document by tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

The document looks like this:

```
<div class="eh">...</div>
...
<section class="g">...</section> <!-- div 1 -->
...
<section class="g">...</section> <!-- div 1 -->
...
<div class="eh">...</div>
...
<section class="g">...</section> <!-- div 2 -->
...
```

All these tags are on the same tree level. I need to segment the document into groups of the number of divs and attach sections to their corresponding div.

The expected result is a list like `[div1, section1, section2, div2, section3]`. They appear in the order they appear in the HTML.

My current code:

```
bs.find_all(
  ['div', 'section'], 
  {'class': ['eh', 'g']})
```

This works if div and section have different classes.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you most of the way toward your goal.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('temp.htm').read(), 'lxml')
tags = soup.find_all(['div','section'])

for tag in tags:
    print (tag.name, tag)
```

Output:

```
div <div class="eh">...</div>
section <section class="g">...</section>
section <section class="g">...</section>
div <div class="eh">...</div>
section <section class="g">...</section>
section <section class="g">...</section>
section <section class="g">...</section>
section <section class="g">...</section>
```

Notice that items in the soup are output in the order in which tags are listed in `soup.find_all`.

Comment: Thanks. It partly solves my problem. Can this solution by more specific, i.e., finding multiple tags, each with its corresponding class?

Comment: Please explain more fully.

Comment: May I find multiple tags, each associated with its class? Something like: find_all ( ['div', {'class': 'eh'}, 'section', {'class': 'g'}]). I tried: find_all(
  ['div', 'section'], {'class': ['eh', 'g'']}). It works, can I improve it further?

Comment: You should ask a new question about that. This time you should present whatever code you've written, an example of the HTML that you're trying to process and the results you expect.